# LinkedIn asking for user permission even though user has approved them already

Tags: permissions, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

First I am using 
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

for getting the authorization code and then,

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
to get the access token.

The document states that 
"If there is a valid existing permission grant from the user, the authorization screen is by-passed and the user is immediately redirected to the URL provided in the redirect_uri query parameter."

Now suppose a user has granted the permissions to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization,

but when that user is coming to website again, he is trying to login via liknedIn and I am sending authorization request again, but the user is prompted to grant permissions again to the application.

I dont want my user to grant permissions again. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, can you please share your code for the first 2 steps.  I'm trying to do the same, but not able to get access token.  FYI I'm using JavaScript as frontend